# Combine two "for" loops while iterating on first one

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, object

i have seen some answers with itertools like :

```
for x, y in itertools.product([1,2,3], [1,2,3]):
    print x, y
```

but as i have to iterate on attributes from objects from the first list like that :

```
for obj, param in itertools.product(object_list, obj):
    print(param)
```

This throw an error (obj referenced before assignment), otherwise i would not be here obviously, but is there a way to do this that doesn't imply two "for" loops ?

like

```
for obj in object_list:
    for param in obj:
        print(param)
```

Thank you for any answer

Comment: No, I think you need nested loops, so your last snippet seems to be the way to go.

Comment: What is the last *obj* (from `for obj, param in itertools.product(object_list, obj):`)? *product* is designed to **construct** the Cartesian product of the 2 iterables received as arguments (they must exist). Using it to go over the properties of a sequence elements (same as going through the elements of an *2D* array) is conceptually wrong (making this an *XY Problem*), is pretty ugly, and I think it's also less efficient.

Comment: If you don't need to know the object grouping in the loop, you can use `for param in sum(object_list, []):`